# IE 6 display issue categories menu opencart 1.5.1

Tags: html, css

In opencart we are using the li for the sub categories items

http://www.madaboutleisure.com as you can see renders fine with all current browsers but we have to support ie 6

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you still need to support IE6? Only 1.4% of the UK is using IE6 and that number is decreasing. And most of these will be legacy systems in corporations and not at home.

Comment: And furthermore Microsoft is about to force the update to IE 8 or IE 9 during the current year.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need png fixes for IE6, lookup:
http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/

Also add a css to your image links:

```
border: none;
```

Your table in

```
#top_contact_details
```

should float:right instead of being padded...

Hope this helps...